# PDF LaTeX related - putting 2 figures in a page and have n number of figures to put

Tags: floats

I have "n" number of figures, this "n" varies as per need, so how to put 2 figures per page and it goes on continuously until the all figures are put into the TeX file. figures are stored in a folder and accessed from the path.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Should the figures be floats (as the tag suggests)? And how are the figures saved? Please clarify your question.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, i dont know much about float, but figures are saved in a folder, and i have to put those figures one by one (2 per page) along with some caption below each figure.

Comment: If the figures are numbered, inputting is doable, but how do you want to input the captions?

Comment: based on section and subsection, figures will get auto numbered and using makeindex, i will get it. for now, my problem is, caption may be a random text describing the figure, but how to can put 2 figures per page and continue the same pattern until all figures get finished.

Comment: Well, automation only works when all components may be automated. Captioning with "random text" is impossible if the rest is automatically generated. Unfortunately I can't help you with inputting the figures automatically, but adding captions later on. Maybe somebody else can.

Comment: while adding the figures only, i will write the caption such as for figure 1, caption will be "figure 1: first stage", for 2nd figure, "figure 2: second stage", and so on.